# How to highlight the bottom of a word letter by letter?

Tags: html, css

First things first!

**Ingredients:** We have a `<input type="text"/>`.

**Problem:** Every time the user types, delete or change a letter, under the text area must grow a line, as shown in the visual demo. I imagined different solutions:

- *dynamic size*: the part of the line that adds/deletes/changes to the precedent one has the exact width of the letter added/deleted/changed.
- *static size*: the part of the line that adds/deletes/changes to the precedent one doesn't count the exact width of the letter added/deleted/changed.

**Question:** How can I achieve one of those goals with HTML5 + CSS3 (**preferibly** without using javascript/jQuery) so the underline will grow (from left to right) while the user changes the text inside the input? **I'M ASKING FOR THE ANIMATION.**

**Actual visual DEMO**: From first to the last step, the user is typing, then he finished and as last, he delete everything.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**[EDIT]:** Note that the *placeholder* word in the visual demos is not random: the input tag contains everything, so if the user types something, then the underline is present and showed with the animation I'm asking for, otherwise the placeholder without any underline is showed. What I'm asking is the animation/transition! The underline of the input tag will seems to the user like it's growing/decreasing.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: You mean create a text line with the preview of the typed text on the input?

Comment: Read your question three times and still don’t know what you are trying to do. Is the 'placeholder' some autosuggested input or what’s going on there?

Comment: the question still unclear, please more explanation will be very helpful. Also, add some explanation on the visual demo that you provided.

Comment: I'm trying to be more clear as possible, sorry and thanks to everyone who's still trying to understand.

Comment: @enriquo you said "under the text area must grow a line" do you mean a bar below the input field, so it fills the bar from 0 to %100? something like this : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_progressbar1&stacked=h

Comment: Yeah, you understood, but it has to follow the inserted text. @iSR5

Comment: @enriquo then CSS is not your solution. You need to use Javascript to make it handle the changes.

Comment: As I wrote and I quote: "__PREFERIBLY__ without using javascript/jQuery" so a solution that provides jQuery/JS is still acceptable. @iSR5

Comment: @enriquo take a look at this : http://carlofontanos.com/character-count-with-live-progress-bar-using-jquery/

Comment: @iSR5 saw, but that is not the visual thing that I got in mind. I just want to know how to make the line follow the text with an animation, that's all.

Comment: @enriquo Describe "visual thing" that you have in mind.?

Comment: You type "a" and then and underline which the length is defined _dynamically_ or _statically_ "grow" from left to right under the __a__ you typed in the <input> tag. You delete it and then the line now decreases. All tose changes must have a transition, that is what I'm asking for. @iSR5

Comment: @enriquo check Sqnkov answer, is it what you need?

Answer (score 3):

Just use css text-decoration property of input field

**input {text-decoration: underline; }**

Use this to achieve your requirement

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't well formed. I haven't asked for a static styling, but for something that changes while the text changes.

Comment: Please go through this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366411/keep-input-placeholder-always-visible

Comment: It will give you some idea

Comment: As now my question seems clearer, I can answer you that (and I quote myself): _ASKING FOR THE ANIMATION_ . Also I understand that my DEMO is not th best, but it's clear that I'm not asking for the palceholder to be left n the input. Instead I'm looking for the animation of the underline that grows or decrease as the input gros or decrease. @Daniel A Sathish Kumar

Answer (score 1):

not sure if i understood what you want. but it seems kind of simple. just use this

```css
input {
 text-decoration:underline
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="insert text">
```

EDIT : sorry for the duplicate answer . Stackoverflow went in maintenance
mode while i was answering and the answer appeared now

Comment: Saw your edit. No worries for me I will not flag this.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible trough the use of pseudo-elements , some CSS trickery for the width and a `:hover` setting for your anchor, to control your pseudo-elements.

```css
.link  {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  color: tomato;
}

.link::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3366FF;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.link:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.link:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href='#'>This link here</a>
```

Comment: The visual result is what I want to achieve, but the underline has to be anchored to the change of new text. @Sqnkov