# How to Add a Class to HTML when clicking on a field?

Tags: html, css, forms, label

On this page
https://www.startwithsquare1.com/signup/
When you click on any of the fields it adds "-top" to the "sq-input sq-input_light -inverse" class. Is there a way to add this without javascript? If I do have to use JS, how would I do it? I am trying to achieve how the label scales up when you click on the field.

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you tried anything already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery addclass/removeclass on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295982/jquery-addclass-removeclass-on-click)

Comment: Add your code here, it will be very helpful to diagnose your problem

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366411/keep-input-placeholder-always-visible/38366587#38366587

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easy do it with HTML and CSS code. This is called Floating Placeholder and you need to:

Here's the example and at the end of the answer is the link to a Video Tutorial if you have any more doubt, but the main thing is the `class:focus` .

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: url(college.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 75%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 700px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 45px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border :1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.container h1
{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgb(66,133,244);
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.container input
{
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 55%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  border:none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
}

.container input[type="submit"]
{
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor : pointer;
  background: rgb(66,133,244);
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.container input[type="submit"]:hover
{
  background: #34F458;
  color: #fff;
}

.container form div
{
  position: relative;
}
.container form div label
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.container input:focus ~label,
.container input:valid ~label
{
  left: 0;
  top: -20px;
  color: rgb(66,133,244);
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.container input:focus,
.container input:valid
{
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(66,133,244);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div>
      <input type="email" name="" required="">
      <label>Email id</label>   
      </div>
      <div>
      <input type="password" name="" required="">
      <label>Password</label>   
      </div>
      <div>
      <input type="password" name="" required="">
      <label>Re-Enter Password</label>   
      </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[VIDEO TUTORIAL](https://youtu.be/xTShp-tZbD0): https://youtu.be/xTShp-tZbD0

Answer (score 1):

Following is the HTML -

```
<div id="div1" class="abc">
   <....inside tags...>
</div>
```

Following is the js -

```
var x = document.getElementById("div1");  
x.className += " otherclass";
```

Otherclass is is the name of the class added.

you can also refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to do so

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p:first").addClass("intro");
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.intro {
    font-size: 45px;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Add a class name to the first p element</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript to do this. Function example:

```
function addClass() {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("sq-input");
    element.classList.add("-top");
}
```

For more information: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think such manipulations are **bad practice**.
They are always feels like a crutch.

If you are dont want to waste your time on javascript, then
try [Elemental](https://github.com/Natteke/SmokinSexySoftware/tree/master/packages/Elemental), it is pretty easy to use, and it's 3kb only.

Your page gives **503** error, so i will just try to make an example.

```
var element = document.querySelector('.element');
element.addEventListener('click', function () {
  Elemental.add(this, 'myNewCssClass');
})
```

It is easy to use, and it works fast